# My bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out the bootstrap carousel but it just won't work. I've done lots of research and checked again and again yet it still won't work. 
Can anyone tell me why?(I"m just starting out so some detailed explanation will be very much appreciated tq)

Here's my code.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/4495439099001/4495439099001_5325814229001_5305215728001-vs.jpg?pubId=4495439099001&videoId=5305215728001">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.asianews.it/files/img/INDIA_-_0907_-_Vescovo_di_Vasai_su_MT.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.crossroadsinitiative.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Mother-Teresa-of-Calcutta-Mother-Teresas-National-Prayer-Breakfast-Message.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After adding **Bootstrap** & **jQuery** CDN's,

It seems that your carousel working properly,

You have to check one of these:

- Add jQuery reference if you didn't.
- If you already have jQuery make sure that it's before bootstrap javascript.
- If bootstrap and jQuery are downloaded and you have them locally, make sure that you are using the right link to documents.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/4495439099001/4495439099001_5325814229001_5305215728001-vs.jpg?pubId=4495439099001&videoId=5305215728001">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.asianews.it/files/img/INDIA_-_0907_-_Vescovo_di_Vasai_su_MT.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.crossroadsinitiative.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Mother-Teresa-of-Calcutta-Mother-Teresas-National-Prayer-Breakfast-Message.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Turns out I was just missing a jQuery reference. Thank you very much :)

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Comment: I had this problem just today! This saved me: "If you already have jQuery make sure that it's before bootstrap javascript." Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Try to post complete code which can be run and so we can directly edit there. Following is output. You didn't imported libraries

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">

     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide to="2"></li>
     </ol>

     <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active">
         <img src="https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/4495439099001/4495439099001_5325814229001_5305215728001-vs.jpg?pubId=4495439099001&videoId=5305215728001">
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         <img src="http://www.asianews.it/files/img/INDIA_-_0907_-_Vescovo_di_Vasai_su_MT.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         <img src="https://www.crossroadsinitiative.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Mother-Teresa-of-Calcutta-Mother-Teresas-National-Prayer-Breakfast-Message.jpg">
       </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

  </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

bro I was facing the same probleme, and i didn't actually find out the solution in many tutorials, so i decided to start over by puting the origin bootstrap **starter template** , then it works well for me .

here is the link of the template:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

hope that helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35375038)